# How to disable Ubuntu Software Centre for user?

Tags: software-center, users

As administrator I want to be sure user can not download inappropriate applications.

Comment: Look at System -->Admin -->Uers and Groups. Highlight the user and click Preperties, lok at the user privileges tab.

Answer (score 4):

If "user" is not an administrator they will not be able to install software without the administrator password.

Go to System Settings > User Accounts, click unlock at the top and change "user" to standard if needed.

[image: user accounts]

Answer (score 1):

Since user needs administration rights to install software, you can remove him from `sudoers`. Use command `visudo` to open sudoers file and remove the user you want.

Comment: Very graceful. :) You need root access to edit `visudo`.

Comment: link: [Remove sudoers discusson on linuxquestions] (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-remove-a-user-from-sudoer-list-933423/)

Comment: @loklaan Just as a heads-up, `visudo` is not edited; it calls an editor, and checks syntax after edits are complete.